# Tuple pattern matching fails

Tags: f#, tuples, pattern-matching

I want to match a tuple with four items.

```
let tupleVar = (1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00)
let verboseMsg (tupleInput: tuple) = 
    match tupleInput with
    | (var1, var2, var3, var4) -> printfn "4 part tuple: %f %f %f %f" var1 var2 var3 var4
    | (var1, var2, var3) -> printfn "3-part tuple: %f %f %f" var1 var2 var3
```

While this tuple is not complete, it already throws this error on the first matching line:

```
ParserError: 
Line |
   3 |      | (var1, var2, var3, var4) -> printfn "4 part tuple: %f %f %f %f" …
     |             ~
     | Missing argument in parameter list.
```

I thought that I can create the variables 'var1', etc. in this matching class. Eventually I want to check the tuple for nulls within the tuple, but it already fails here.

Why do I get this error?

I took the example from "Tuple Pattern" of the official Microsoft site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#tuple-pattern

Comment: You're trying to match your parameter as both 4-tuple and a 3-tuple. It can't be both, you have to pick one type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fyodor points out, a 3-tuple and a 4-tuple are two different types, so you can't match on both at the same time. I think what you probably want instead is to match on a list type, since lists can be of variable length:

```ml
let listVar = [1.00; 2.00; 3.00; 4.00]
let verboseMsg listInput = 
    match listInput with
    | [var1; var2; var3; var4] -> printfn "4 part list: %f %f %f %f" var1 var2 var3 var4
    | [var1; var2; var3] -> printfn "3-part list: %f %f %f" var1 var2 var3

verboseMsg listVar   // 4 part list: 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer of Brian Berns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71367623) is spot on: you cannot do it with pattern matching. Besides matching on variable-length data types, what you could also do is object-orientated method overloading, but there is an additional twist. Consider:

```
type Foo = Foo with
    static member T (var1, var2, var3, var4) = printfn "4 part tuple: %f %f %f %f" var1 var2 var3 var4
    static member T (var1, var2, var3) = printfn "3-part tuple: %f %f %f" var1 var2 var3

Foo.T (1., 2., 3., 4.)
Foo.T (1., 2., 3.)
```

That works. What about tuples bound to variables?

```
let t4 = 1., 2., 3., 4.
let t3 = 1., 2., 3.
```

Passed as arguments, they can be considered as of type `(float * float * float * float)`, and `(float * float * float)`, which are different beasts altogether than the types `float * float * float * float` and `float * float * float` they purport to possess.

```
type Foo with
    static member T ((var1, var2, var3, var4)) = Foo.T (var1, var2, var3, var4)
    static member T ((var1, var2, var3)) = Foo.T (var1, var2, var3)

Foo.T t4
Foo.T t3
```